# Symfony 3 FOSUserBundle 'Error: Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\User as array'

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

I was working on a simple controller for my Symfony3 app with FOSUserBundle to update the user's e-mail address.

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$user->setEmail($email);
```

Returns this error on the second line.

```
Error: Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\User as array
```

I'm clearly not using the object as an array, considering that I am using a method of the BaseUser class, so I am at a loss with why it is throwing this error.

EDIT:

Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/portfolio/settings", name="portfolio_settings")
 */
public function settingsAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $email_form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('change_email', FormType::class, $user)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'label' => 'E-Mail',
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Save'
        ))
        ->getForm();
    $password_form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('change_password', FormType::class, $user)
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $email_form->handleRequest($request);
    $password_form->handleRequest($request);
    if($email_form->isValid()){
        $data = $email_form->getData();
        $user->setEmail($data['email']);
        $em->persist($user);
        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Your E-Mail address has been updated successfully'
        );
    }
    $em->flush();
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Portfolio:settings.html.twig', array(
        'email' => $email_form->createView(),
        'password' => $password_form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Stack Trace

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\User as array
at n/a
    in /var/www/html/scnce/src/AppBundle/Controller/PortfolioController.php line 114
```

Line 114 is

```
$user->setEmail($data['email']);
```

Comment: Something leads me to believe that this isn't where the error is occurring.  Can you post the full stack trace and the whole file where this error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the first answer.

In Symfony, when you create a form using an entity, the form method `getData()` will return the entity originally passed to it.  So, if you've already got that entity (object), there's no need to call `getData()`  Also the `handleRequest()` already changed the entity's values for you based on your form.  Unless in the form field you specified `'mapped' => false` in the options.

Example

```
/**
 * @Route("/portfolio/settings", name="portfolio_settings")
 */
public function settingsAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $email_form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('change_email', FormType::class, $user)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'label' => 'E-Mail',
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Save'
        ))
        ->getForm();

    $email_form->handleRequest($request);

    if($email_form->isValid()){
        // Here we can persist the user, it's field for email have already been modified by ->handleRequest($request);
        // In fact if you var_dump($user->getEmail()) you'll see it's already your new value.
        $em->persist($user);
        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Your E-Mail address has been updated successfully'
        );
        // I moved your flush here, because it's more appropriate to only flush when we've actually made a change.
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Portfolio:settings.html.twig', array(
        'email' => $email_form->createView(),
        'password' => $password_form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

You can find all this and more in the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

In the end `$data = $form->getData()` was returning your User Entity, so `$data['email']` was giving you the error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes much more sense, and makes things a lot simpler. It works great now, Thanks! Time to tidy up the code.

Answer (score 0):

`$data = $email_form->getData();`

```
$user->setEmail($data['email']);
```

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot
>   use object of type AppBundle\Entity\User as array

It's saying that `$data` is your entity User ...

*(sorry, short answer)*